# Excel 2010 - Show cell contents - wrong number appearance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I was trying to create a simple function in Excel VBA editor. When I click on a cell within the certain range, I want to copy its value into another cell I have set.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then     
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:N15")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Value = Target.Value
    End If        
  End If        
End Sub
```

However, when a cell contains pure numbers, e.g. 22, the value that appears on B17 is "2200%", which is not what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: I put it into my Excel and it works fine, returns 22 in cell B17. Two questions; what version of Excel are you using, and have you ensured B17's number format is set to number not percentage?

Comment: @CLockeWork True, it was on percentage. I added the code on a file I was given, so I was not aware of that change.

Comment: Random formatting from other users is the bane of my life :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments above. The problem was that B17 format was set to "percentage".